# Finding Inverse of Function With Two Instances of X

Tags: trigonometry, functional-equations, inverse

I need to find $f^{-1}(2)$ where $f(x) = 2 + x^2 + tan(πx/2)$

I know can substitute $f(x)$ with $y$ and swap $x$ and $y$:
$$x = 2 + y^2 + tan(πy/2)$$

But I'm having trouble eliminating the tangent:
$$y^2 + tan(πy/2) = x - 2$$

Could someone please tell me how I should continue?  Is there any way to factor y out of $tan(πy/2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case- it's actually easy. Note that If $0 \leq x \leq 1$ then $f(x) \geq 2$ with equality only when $x=0$. So that gives you one solution $f^{-1}(2)=0$. Question is: are there other solutions? When $1<x<2$ the tan term is negative, and we might have a solution, if $x^2=tan\dfrac{\pi x}{2}$ with $1<x<2$. Is there such a solution? Can you proceed?

Comment: Oh, I guess I wasn't considering the domain of tan.  I'm still wrapping my head around it, but that makes some sense.  Thanks